# How to suppress message of package leaflet?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, r-markdown, shiny-server

I am using 'leaflet' package by R-studio to plot my geo-data. I am creating Rmarkdown file for the same.

Everything works fine. But I get following message in the beginning in Rmarkdown output file:

> ### Assuming 'lng' and 'lat' are longitude and latitude, respectively

I have tried my best to suppress this message, but no success so far.
It's not harmful but irritating!!!
**The code:**

```
`{r, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE} options(warn=-1) 
long = runif(40, -87, -80) 
lat = runif(40, 25, 42) 
m = leaflet() %>% addTiles() 
df = data.frame( lng=long, lat=lat,size = runif(40, 5, 20), color = sample(colors(), 40)) 
m = leaflet(df) %>% addTiles() 
m %>% addCircleMarkers(radius = runif(40, 4, 10), color = c('red','blue','green'))`
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you are actually running? It's easier to help with a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Be clear which functions you are using and what data you as passing in.

Comment: You should edit your original question to include the code rather than trying to stuff it in the comments. That way you can have proper formatting.

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick ! Just added the code there.

Comment: Don't know why am I getting downvotes :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the `message` option in the chunk header, e.g.

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
````